# Changing a query to count number of unique values rather than total rows

Tags: php, mysql

For the query below, some rows have the same value for a field called "zip."  How can I count how many unique values for "zip" rather than total rows?

```
$presult = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) from submission ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT zip) AS unique_zip_cnt
  FROM submission
```

Comment: I didn't see your post after I posted mine, for some reason a new answer bar didn't pop up when I was posting. I've deleted mine and upvoted yours, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @Recursed: definitely not your mistake but curious why community did that :-S